# Under what conditions do the iterations $x^{(t+1)}=f(x^{(t)})$ converge?

Tags: real-analysis

In particular if we know that $f$ is bounded (on $\mathbb{R} $) and smooth and a solution exists for $x-f(x)=0$, can we guarantee the convergence of the above iterations to the solution of the equation?

Comment: Obviously not. Let $f(x)=-x$

Comment: @almagest 'bounded' function

Comment: Ok. $f(x)=-x$ for $|x|\le1$ and 2 for $x>1$. The iterations fail to converge for $0<x<1$.

Comment: OK.  Maybe I need to be more careful in framing the question. I should have mentioned that $f(x) $ is smooth and bounded in $R$.  Sorry

Comment: Smoothness and boundedness are offtopic here, try $f(x)=-2\sin x$ with $x_0>0$ solving $x_0=2\sin x_0$.

Comment: Thanks.  So,  when do the above iterations work.  Any suggestion for what I should check?

Comment: $k$-Lipschitz with $k<1$ works, naturally, apart from that...

Comment: Ohh.  OK.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are dealing with an FPI (Fixed Point Iteration). It's know that $x^{t+1} = f(x^{t})$ where $f$ is continuosly differentiable, will converge (locally) to the **fixed point**  $r = f(r)$, iff $|f'(r)| < 1$.

Then it's simple to find functions that diverges. For example $f(x) =c_0\arctan(x) \ \ \forall x \in \mathbb{R}$ and $c_0 > 1$. It has fixed point $f(0)=0$, $|f'(0)| = c_0  > 1$ and is bounded and smooth as you wanted.

Comment: Thanks.  That solves my problem.